# Segue from xib to storyboard objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Assume there are 2 UIViewControllers in the storyboard,say 'A' and 'B'. Also, there is a xib file,say 'C', with .h and .m files. 'A' accesses a method of C which adds its own view on A's view. C also has a method which does [self.view removeFromSuperView].
What I wish to do is after the C's view is removed,I want to segue to B.

Note: I'm not using a navigation view controller in my implementation.

What I've tried so far('poi' below is B's storyboard ID):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
UIStoryboard * myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
B *chartpage = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"poi"];
[self presentModalViewController:chartpage animated:YES];
```

WARNING: "*Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged*" and also, the method 'presentModalViewController' is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call window's rootViewController's presentViewController:animated:completion: method.

Comment: Do you mean parentViewController and not rootViewController, coz rootViewController would return the first most viewController in the storyboard. I agree, that acc to my ques they both are the same, but what if A was not the rootViewController(first viewController in the storyboard)?

Comment: I tried  [self.parentViewController presentViewController:chartpage animated:YES completion:nil];
I guess Im getting parentViewController as null as nothing happens

Comment: Then I tried getting the parentViewController using its storyboard id.After that if I either do 'performSegueWithIdentifier' or 'presentViewController' I get:


Warning: Attempt to present <B: 0x7916f880> on <A: 0x7916fdf0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!